# Ethernaut CoinFlip Solution not working

Tags: solidity, remix, proxy-contracts

I am trying to solve the [CoinFlip puzzle](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9240670dbd6476e6a32055E52A0b0756abd26fd2) from Ethernaut

- [This is my instance of the CoinFlip Contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xE11110b8e18450008C79eD1A5FB5Ca48347a5Dd5).
- [My CoinFlipCaller contract is here](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x6a61dfa75c5705520e6d33423432e43b5cc4266a).

Every time I run my `flipIt` function through remix it goes through fine and runs, but it never hits the official CoinFlip Contract. as you can see from [etherscan](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xE11110b8e18450008C79eD1A5FB5Ca48347a5Dd5).

I even ran the flip function from the CoinFlip contract manually through remix in my previous instance and it works fine. I attempted a new instance because I'm honestly not sure what's going on.

I also checked out Smart Contract Programmers [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aQErpWPLbk) and I don't think I'm missing anything in terms of global variables or imports for interacting with an already deployed contract using another contract.

As a last attempt I tried this [solution](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-solve-the-level-3-of-the-ethernaut-game) and it still didn't work.

My only guess is that perhaps the CoinFlip flip function needs to be external? But people have solved it so I don't know.

Every thing compiles fine and I'm using the 0.8.0 compiler. Here is my code below in Remix:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract CoinFlipCaller {

  uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

  function flipIt(address _coinFlipAddress) external {
    uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1));
    uint256 coinflip = blockValue / FACTOR;
    bool side = coinflip == 1 ? true : false;
    CoinFlip coinFlipContract = CoinFlip(_coinFlipAddress);
    coinFlipContract.flip(side);
  }

}

contract CoinFlip {

  uint256 public consecutiveWins;
  uint256 lastHash;
  uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

  constructor() {
    consecutiveWins = 0;
  }

  function flip(bool _guess) public returns (bool) {
    uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1));

    if (lastHash == blockValue) {
      revert();
    }

    lastHash = blockValue;
    uint256 coinFlip = blockValue / FACTOR;
    bool side = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;

    if (side == _guess) {
      consecutiveWins++;
      return true;
    } else {
      consecutiveWins = 0;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the link you sent. It did 'hit' the 'CoinFlip' contract. you need to check internal transaction: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xE11110b8e18450008C79eD1A5FB5Ca48347a5Dd5#internaltx

Comment: Well that answers that, of course it's something silly like that haha. I ran the flipIt function again and theres like a 10 second delay after the flipIt transaction finishes and the CoinFlip contract to show an internal transaction, so future viewers be patient with etherscan updates. Thanks for pointing that out @minhhn2910

Comment: another thing for future viewers make sure to raise your gas limit as it kept failing every now and then due to an out of gas error.